# Развертывание веб приложения Grails на локальном компьютере

Tags: groovy, веб-программирование, java, развертывание

Добрый день, сообщество. Я студент, пишу веб приложение, используя фреймворк Grails (ранее писал на чистой Java с фреймворком Spring). Возник вопрос: как развернуть свое приложение на локальном компьютере (не путать с localhost) что бы к нему был доступ из сети, или же подскажите бесплатные онлайн хостинги, желательно с инструкциями по развертыванию?

Answer (score 1):

Без разницы, Grails или не Grails. Для любого сервера:

- Убедиться, что у вас белый IP-адрес. В противном случае придется использовать что-то из разряда DynDNS.
- Запустить приложение, используя в качестве хоста внешний сетевой интерфейс (обычно достаточно 0.0.0.0).
- Открыть порт на машине, на которой запущен сервер.
- Если выход в интернет через роутер - скорее всего нужно будет пробросить порт на нем (так как внешний IP-адрес будет у роутера).

PS. "Хостинг" в контексте java-сервера это какое-то извращенное понятие. Комфортно вы будете себя чувствовать на VDS сервере. Можете попробовать бесплатный годовой micro-instance от Amazon Web Cloud.